# Replicate %>% behavior with |>

Tags: r

I have a data:

```
set.seed(123)
df_2 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 10, expr = sample(x = 1:4, size = 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

I tried replicate the behavior of `mutate` and `arrange` with `|>` pipe. Something like (it's wrong):

```
df_2 |> 
  cbind(lapply(X = (`[`)(c("x.1", "x.2")), FUN = function(x) {
    sum(x)
  }) |> 
    sort(x = c("x.1", "x.4")))
```

> Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Expected result:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_2 %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = c("x.1", "x.4"), .fns = ~ sum(.), .names = "r{col}")) %>% 
  arrange(x.1, x.4)

   x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4 x.5 x.6 x.7 x.8 x.9 x.10 rx.1 rx.4
1    1   3   3   2   1   4   2   4   1    4   25   26
2    1   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   2    3   25   26
3    1   4   1   4   4   3   3   2   4    4   25   26
4    2   4   3   2   2   3   2   4   3    3   25   26
5    2   2   2   4   2   3   4   3   2    3   25   26
6    3   4   3   2   3   3   3   4   1    4   25   26
7    3   3   1   2   4   1   2   4   3    1   25   26
8    4   1   3   2   2   1   3   1   3    4   25   26
9    4   2   4   3   4   2   2   4   1    1   25   26
10   4   2   1   3   2   3   1   2   2    4   25   26
```

Comment: That is simply not how the `sort()` function works. It has nothing to do with the pipe. Check out the help file for it.

Comment: Your main issue is that `dplyr` functions are all made to work on data frames, with the data frame as the first argument. `sort` isn't. Nothing to do with the kind of pipe, as Adam says.

Comment: You can use the base `|>` pipe with `dplyr` verbs just fine. You need to delete your unnecessary `.data = .`, but `df_2 |>
  mutate(across(.cols = c("x.1", "x.4"), .fns = ~ sum(.), .names = "r{col}")) |> 
  arrange(x.1, x.4)` works just as well as using `%>%`.

Comment: Similarly using the `magrittr` pipe with the base functions `df_2 %>%
  cbind(lapply(X = (\`[\`)(c("x.1", "x.2")), FUN = function(x) {
    sum(x)
  }) %>%
    sort(c("x.1", "x.4")))` fails the same way, because as the 2nd sentence of the `?sort` help page says, *"For ordering along more than one variable, e.g., for sorting data frames, see order."* But `order` works with `[`, which doesn't play super well with piping, regardless of whether you use `|>` or `%>%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the left hand side more than once on the right hand side define a function on the right hand side when using |> .  We have defined the functions inline but could define them prior to the pipeline, if desired.

```
df_2 |>
  (\(x) cbind(x, r = lapply(x[c("x.1", "x.4")], sum)))() |>
  (\(x) x[order(x$x.1, x$x.4), ])()
```

giving:

```
   x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4 x.5 x.6 x.7 x.8 x.9 x.10 r.x.1 r.x.4
10   1   3   2   4   3   1   1   4   1    3    24    24
6    2   3   3   1   1   4   2   2   2    1    24    24
7    2   4   4   3   1   2   1   4   3    1    24    24
8    2   1   2   3   2   1   1   3   3    2    24    24
4    2   1   1   4   1   1   3   1   4    2    24    24
1    3   4   1   1   3   4   1   2   2    2    24    24
9    3   3   3   1   3   2   3   4   4    3    24    24
2    3   2   4   2   4   1   4   1   2    2    24    24
5    3   2   1   2   3   3   1   3   2    4    24    24
3    3   2   1   3   2   3   4   3   3    1    24    24
```

If the main purpose of this is to use a pipeline without any packages another approach which is pipeline-like is the Bizarro pipe (which is not actually a pipe but looks like one).

```
df_2 ->.;
  cbind(., r = lapply(.[c("x.1", "x.4")], sum)) ->.;
  .[order(.$x.1, .$x.4), ]
```